# How to take user input via EditText and do stuff with it

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I've searched the site and I have found similar questions, and I have implemented those solutions, but to no avail. What I'm trying to do: I just wanted to get a little experience with programming for Android so I was trying to make a hex/dec/bin/oct calculator.

I have an EditText for decimal, hexadecimal, binary and octal. There a "convert from" button next to each of them. So if you click the button to convert from octal, it'll output the corresponding conversion to the others' EditText fields.

This is the improved version of the code I tried to use for the from decimal function that Lucifer suggested, but still does not solve the problem:

```
public void dec(View view) {
final EditText decimal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editDec);
final EditText hex = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editHex);
final EditText bin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editBin);
final EditText oct = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editOct);
String deci = decimal.getText().toString();
hex.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(deci,16)));
bin.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(deci,2)));
oct.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(deci,8)));
}
```

The current error that I'm getting

```
02-08 00:04:32.143: E/AndroidRuntime(409): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "54"
```

"54" being the number I tried to enter in the decimal EditText.

I think it's saying that it failed to find the resource with the id of the text input, but I'm not trying to fetch the text as an ID, I want it as text.

I'm assuming I've messed something simple up, but it eludes me.

Here's one of the EditTexts it is trying to fetch from

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/editHex"
android:layout_width="100dp" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="11.38"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
android:inputType="text" >
</EditText>
```

The decimal, binary, and octal inputs use an inputType of "number"

Comment: Maybe you should read through this example given by Google. [Form Stuff - EditText](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html#EditText)

Comment: what line is the error, make it more obvious.

Comment: Use debugger and log cat you will find solution.

Comment: @aneal, I've checked that page and I didn't see anything that helped with this situation on it.

Comment: @Smith, that first error message is from LogCat. By running the debugger, I received "02-07 23:59:00.562: W/ResourceType(510): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000054" in LogCat. Why is it referring to a text value as a resource number?

Comment: Check out the id of textview and edittext which you have used in code and what is in actual. check id's of respective fields

Comment: can u please post the xml file

Comment: @user936414, do you mean the main.xml file? There are a lot of XML files...

Comment: the xml in which you have declared these edittexts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your code is in-correct, 
You are trying to convert an Integer Value to Hexa,Binary & Octal Number, but,

```
Integer.parseInt(deci,16)  Integer.parseInt(deci,2)  Integer.parseInt(deci,8)
```

is used to convert deci variable in to Hexa, Binary and Ocatal, which means you were performing reverse operation bymistake.

Checkout my updated code, it is the output you wanted.

```
public void dec(View view) 
{
    try
    {
        EditText decimal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editDec);
        EditText hex = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editHex);
        EditText bin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editBin);
        EditText oct = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editOct);
        int deci = Integer.parseInt(decimal.getText().toString().trim());

        System.out.println ( "Original " + deci );
        System.out.println ( "Hexa : " + Integer.toHexString(deci) );
        System.out.println ( "Deci :" + Integer.toBinaryString(deci));
        System.out.println ( "Oct : " + Integer.toOctalString(deci) );

        hex.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.toHexString(deci)));
        bin.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.toBinaryString(deci)));
        oct.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.toOctalString(deci)));
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        System.out.println ( "Exception : " + e.toString() );
    }
}
```

when you are setting Text in to EditText make sure you are passing String format in it.

Comment: New error: 02-08 00:04:32.143: E/AndroidRuntime(409): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "54"

54 being what I typed in, of course.

Comment: well then try System.out.println() and check at consol.

Comment: It has gone back to giving me this error: 02-08 00:58:28.586: E/AndroidRuntime(396): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "58"

Comment: ok do one thing, upload your xml code too, I will create one project here in my computer & check it , correct it & give you solution

Comment: I have done it, actually , you were doing reverse thing... See my updated code, it is the output you want.

Comment: I wrote a JavaScript (I do mean Script, not Java) based version of this and did it correctly, so I don't know what caused me to make the stupid mistake in this one. Thanks for fixing it though.

Comment: you welcome dear, even I also learn new thing from this question.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing an int to setText, and so it thinks you're trying to tell it the id of a resource. You need to pass it a string instead (or more correctly a CharSequence, but a string will do fine), so something like

```
hex.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(deci,16)));
```

Comment: Your solution was the same as Lucifer, which means it's probably correct, but unfortunately wouldn't work for me. It said that my input was an invalid int.

Comment: So, you have more than one issue, that was the first one.

Answer (score 1):

```
hex.setText(Integer.parseInt(deci,16));
```

`EditText.setText(int ResId)`, if you just pass an Integer value, it will accept it, in your case -> it accepts it as a resource id, and it's not available that's why the error occured.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html

so convert the value to string and display it.

```
hex.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(deci,16)));
```

Comment: That's what Lucifer and superfell suggested as well, and it did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

here the method `Integer.parseInt(deci,16)` will be used to convert hexa to decimal.
to convert dec to hexa use `toHexString(deci);` but here decimal should be int.

please check the following code. it will works fine.

public void dec(View view) {

```
    final EditText decimal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editDec);
    final EditText hex = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editHex);
    final EditText bin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editBin);
    final EditText oct = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editOct);
    String deci = decimal.getText().toString().trim();
    hex
            .setText(String.valueOf(Integer.toHexString(Integer
                    .parseInt(deci))));
    bin.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.toBinaryString(Integer
            .parseInt(deci))));
    oct.setText(String.valueOf(Integer
            .toOctalString(Integer.parseInt(deci))));

}
```